# How i can set a value for a SPUtility.MakeReadOnly(); Choice field

Tags: javascript, development, jquery, list-form, sputility

I am working on a SharePoint On-Premises 2013 farm. and inside my Create & Edit form, i want to set a Status Choice field as read-only, then later on to chnage its value inside a JavaScript script.

Now i am using [SPUtility.js](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sputility) to make my Status field as ReadOnly, as follow:-

```
SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('OrderStatus').MakeReadOnly();
```

But when i try to set its value inside my JavaScript as follow (so when user check a checkbox named "Order Start Working", to set the Status = "In Progress"):-

```
$('[id^="OrderStartWorking"][id$="RadioButtonChoiceField0"]').change(function(){
SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('OrderStatus').SetValue("In Progress");
});
```

OR using pure JavaScript appraoch:-

```
$('[id^="OrderStartWorking"][id$="RadioButtonChoiceField0"]').change(function(){
$('[id^="OrderStatus"]').val("In Progress");
});
```

the value did not change to "In Progress"

So I am not sure how i can set a value for a read-only choice list OR if i can remove the ReadOnly from my choice list >> then set its value = "In Progress" >> then make it as ReadOnly again. keeping in mind that i do not want to set the Status choice list as disabled using JavaScript, since in this case the value will not get submitted when i save the Edit/Create forms.

Comment: That’s what I do, I make it editable then set the value, then make it read only again.

Comment: @mannaggia but how i can make a `.MakeReadOnly()` field editable again?is there a method inside SPUtility.js which support this?

Comment: Yes, .MakeEditable()

Comment: @mannaggia `.MakeEditable()` it worked well for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in @mannaggia comment.. MakeEditable() it worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

Read only fields aren't rendered on New/Edit form. Remove read only from choice list.

disable the field on form and set its value using jquery

```
$("#FieldId").prop("disabled", true);
$("#FieldId").val('valuetoset');
```

Comment: but i do not want to hide it, i want to make it ReadOnly so users can view the status, and inside my javascript i want to set the value of the ReadOnly list .. so for example when a user check a checkbox named "Start working" >> the ReadOnly list choice should be set to "In progress" automatically.. and so on..

Comment: Updated the original answer.

Comment: but disabling the choice list will not post back the field when i submit my form,, as mentioned in my original question